# Interpolate unsorted array maintaining the order of the elements

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have a curve given by a set of points and I need to interpolate extra points into it. As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26133597/1391441) apparently the points are not in the proper order, which causes the interpolation to fail:

[image]

I've been applying `zip()` and `sorted()` on my `data` array for an hour, and I haven't been able to interpolate the data properly and maintain the shape of the curve at the same time.

How can I perform a correct interpolation of this curve?

MCEV:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def interp(x):
    N = 1000
    t, xp = np.linspace(0, 1, N), np.linspace(0, 1, len(x))
    return np.interp(t, xp, x)


# Data
a = [[2.0069999999999997, 2.006, 1.9910000000000003, 1.994, 1.9750000000000003, 1.9730000000000005, 1.9509999999999998, 1.9269999999999998, 1.901, 1.873, 1.841, 1.8100000000000003, 0.5200000000000002, 0.457, 0.5860000000000001, 0.4040000000000001, 0.6620000000000001, 1.7750000000000001, 0.7299999999999998, 0.7979999999999998, 0.36300000000000016, 0.4000000000000001, 0.8699999999999999, 0.44700000000000023, 1.74, 0.49700000000000005, 0.9589999999999999, 0.5520000000000003, 0.6209999999999998, 1.054, 1.7049999999999998, 0.6960000000000004, 0.7550000000000001, 1.1720000000000004, 0.8219999999999998, 1.6689999999999998, 0.8959999999999997, 1.635, 1.0129999999999997, 1.328, 1.6649999999999998, 1.6079999999999999, 0.35600000000000004, 0.409, 1.1420000000000001, 1.6309999999999998, 0.3190000000000001, 1.638, 1.5679999999999998, 0.48599999999999993, 1.405, 0.29299999999999987, 0.5820000000000001, 1.597, 1.535, 1.606, 0.25900000000000006, 0.6939999999999997, 1.4969999999999999, 1.565, 1.3060000000000003, 0.23900000000000005, 1.576, 0.8400000000000001, 1.532, 0.2249999999999998, 1.5430000000000001, 1.0159999999999998, 0.21400000000000013, 1.4989999999999999, 1.511, 1.423, 1.4589999999999999, 0.2049999999999998, 0.20200000000000012, 1.478, 1.1460000000000001, 1.4420000000000002, 0.1919999999999999, 1.401, 1.2720000000000002, 0.18199999999999966, 1.323, 0.175, 0.16699999999999998, 0.15999999999999986, 0.16399999999999987, 0.1600000000000003, 0.16499999999999976, 0.15299999999999975, 0.1640000000000003, 0.1530000000000002, 0.14700000000000019, 0.14100000000000018, 0.14100000000000018, 0.14600000000000007, 0.16299999999999998, 0.1620000000000001, 0.1620000000000001, 0.15899999999999997, 0.15600000000000008, 0.15299999999999997, 0.15299999999999997, 0.15299999999999997, 0.15500000000000008, 0.15699999999999997, 0.16099999999999998, 0.16300000000000003, 0.16799999999999998, 0.178, 0.179, 0.192, 0.19699999999999995, 0.21699999999999992, 0.22599999999999992, 0.25500000000000006, 0.298, 0.306, 0.3310000000000001, 0.36899999999999994, 0.425, 0.49399999999999994, 0.5640000000000003, 0.6020000000000001, 0.9580000000000004, 1.1200000000000003, 1.2959999999999996, 1.4319999999999997],
[8.836, 8.838000000000001, 8.861, 8.878, 8.906, 8.93, 8.98, 9.062000000000001, 9.117, 9.178, 9.259, 9.335, 9.384, 9.388, 9.398, 9.419, 9.422, 9.427, 9.45, 9.478, 9.493, 9.511, 9.515, 9.525, 9.536999999999999, 9.543, 9.563, 9.568999999999999, 9.603, 9.622, 9.64, 9.65, 9.689, 9.715, 9.733, 9.74, 9.784, 9.853, 9.873000000000001, 9.888, 9.909, 9.914, 9.996, 9.999, 10.0, 10.002, 10.011, 10.014, 10.018, 10.022, 10.022, 10.044, 10.067, 10.1, 10.1, 10.112, 10.125, 10.139, 10.14, 10.205, 10.211, 10.217, 10.217, 10.243, 10.306000000000001, 10.31, 10.323, 10.385, 10.399000000000001, 10.402000000000001, 10.425, 10.472, 10.474, 10.486, 10.528, 10.535, 10.54, 10.646, 10.655000000000001, 10.754, 10.767, 10.780000000000001, 10.834, 10.905000000000001, 11.034, 11.167, 11.26, 11.267, 11.281, 11.312000000000001, 11.323, 11.323, 11.345, 11.367, 11.375, 11.39, 11.399000000000001, 11.468, 11.484, 11.658, 11.837, 12.02, 12.207, 12.315, 12.41, 12.615, 12.837, 12.882, 13.093, 13.362, 13.383000000000001, 13.737, 13.855, 14.25, 14.398, 14.768, 15.137, 15.186, 15.338000000000001, 15.527000000000001, 15.768, 16.067, 16.407, 16.696, 18.689, 19.475, 20.431, 21.356]]

# Interpolate array.
a_i = [interp(a[0]), interp(a[1])]

# Plot.
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax1.set_title('Not interpolated')
ax1.scatter(a[0], a[1], s=30, c='blue', lw=0.1)
ax2.set_title('Interpolated')
ax2.scatter(a_i[0], a_i[1], s=30, c='blue', lw=0.1)
plt.show()
```

Comment: As the old answer says, the problem is with your _data_, not with your interpolation method. When you do the preprocessing steps you mentioned in your previous question (i.e going from blue to red by shifting and discarding points), you're messing up the order of the data points in the blue curve. Try not to do that. I could help you more if you post that preprocessing code.

Comment: I'm not doing any pre-processing now. The data shown in the `a` array in my question *here* is the data I have. I need to interpolate it as it is presented here.

Comment: But what about that blue curve in your old question? Do you still have those data points? If not, this could be hard, because it looks like you have to manually sort your points...

Comment: I don't have the old data points. Pretend they never existed. My question *here* is about how to interpolate a curve given by the data presented *here*.

Comment: Well, then it looks like you have your work cut out for you. Your data is in increasing order of the y-coordinate. Your problem is that your data is _sorted_. Your data shouldn't be sorted according to any coordinate, if you're trying to use interpolate. It should be sorted according to the order _in which you need the interpolation to happen_. The best I can tell you is to use some graphical tool to manually order your data points, or to try and recover your old dataset. I'm out of ideas, otherwise.

Comment: Thanks anyway Praveen!